# Send custom events to browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont know what i am asking is do-able or not. But, still whenever I start a ajax request I want to send `processing` event to the browser, so that it shows the spinning circle in the tab and brings up a progress bar, until the request completes.

Is this possible? If yes, can you point me to correct resource.

Comment: refer this--http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

Comment: @Vivek and @answerers below... please read the question properly and not just the title... @Starx wants the **native** browser spinner and progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make the spinner animate programmatically, but you can simulate the behavior using [a hidden iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694858/can-i-control-the-web-browsers-loading-icon). As long as the iframe is loading, the browser will animate the spinner.

```
var doneLoading = false;

var simulateLoad = function () {
    var ifrm = document.createElement('IFRAME');
    //make dummy.html a sufficiently large file
    ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'dummy.html?' + Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
    ifrm.style.display = 'none';
    ifrm.onload = function () {
        if(!doneLoading) {
            document.body.removeChild(ifrm);
            simulateLoad();
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}

var startLoad = function () {
    doneLoading = false;
    simulateLoad();
}

var endLoad = function () {
    doneLoading = true;
}
```

Comment: Well, then tell me, how can I load some page or send some POST request and utilize an hidden iframe to simulate their loading and completion.

Comment: Ive added sample code above.  It workes for me, but this solution seems kind of hacky. You're essentially using a network trip to achieve a UI effect.

Comment: when you said, to make dummy.html a sufficiently large file, how will it become relative to my ajax requests?, what if the page i am requesting to, is a sufficiently small one. I am confused. Please do not find me annoying and help me clear this.

Comment: I guess what I was trying to say, is that, if you know your 'loading' time is going to be relatively long, you can increase the size of the dummy file to reduce the number of refreshes.   But even a small dummy.html will work; the code will just reload it more often. (This actually may be a better solution if you're dealing with ajax requests that take variable amount of time)